# Attempt to update your production data failed - Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

**Where:**
In build -> Actions -> Upload content via Google Sheets

**Problem:** I have the trivia template selected. I've already created a sheet and uploaded and deployed my action. Now I figured out that one of my questions had a wrong answer. So I updated the sheet and then went back to the actions tab to upload content via google sheets
[image: Upload content via Google Sheets image]

Then I clicked on UPDATE TEST and tested my app in the simulator. The changes were reflected.

Then I clicked on UPDATE PROD and I get the following message
[image: Attempt to update your production data failed]

On doing further investigation I found out that the GET request is returning a 403 error

[image: Failed Get request]

and in the Network tab, this is the response I'm getting:

[image]

I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: A 403 HTTP error indicates you're forbidden from making that API call. You may want to try to UPDATE TEST and then submit to production afterwards.

Comment: @NickFelker if you read the question carefully, I've mentioned that I clicked on the UPDATE TEST first and then clicked on Submit to Production

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same situation.

However, there is a workaround or it must be the right action when upgrading your Q&A Sheet.  It is to use "submit for production" in Deploy>Release sidebar.  See [attached image].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtqKF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I think you have changed the Google Sheet's name and questions per page, so it gives an error. If you give the same name and questions per page it is taking i.e. updating.

Comment: I'll check and report back